# Running Cassandra on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cassandra

I am trying to run Cassandra on my mac.
I installed it following the steps detailed here: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/getting_started/install_singlenode_root

but when I run:

```
bin/nodetool ring –h localhost
```

I get the following error message:

```
Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

How can I make cassandra work?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ancient docs. On a recent version of Cassandra, run the command like this:

bin/nodetool -h localhost ring (see http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsRing.html)

If you installed vnodes (the default), use nodetool status for an easier-to-read output.

Please use these docs or the docs that match your installation, I doubt you installed Cassandra 1.0. Please check the installation instructions that match the version you downloaded.

CORRECTION: the nodetool ring command worked for me using options in any position on 2.0.10:

> bin/nodetool -h localhost ring

```
bin/nodetool ring -h localhost
```

and using --h instead of -h

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug in the JDK but it is not going to stop you from running Cassandra.
What you can do is to set JAVA_HOME variable explicitly.

It will not solve the bug, but it might remedy the error.

Comment: thanks, when running `bin/nodetool ring –-h localhost` I now get 

`Error: The keyspace localhost, does not exist`
How can I fix this?

Comment: @Spearfisher The error message is quite clear. You aren't supplying a Keyspace. `nodetool ring keycap --h host`

Answer (score 0):

This is problem with jdk version, so you have to do the following

1. unset JAVA_HOME from your terminal.
2. edit nodetool and assign JAVA variable with jdk version less than jdk7.

   ```
   JAVA = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.6.0_xx.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
   ```
3. then run nodetool, you should be able to go without any issue.